# Is it possible to order a replacement key?

Tags: keyboard

The large   <kbd>0</kbd>   on my Apple keyboard (came with my 2008 Mac Mini) has fallen out, and upon my attempt to put it back in, a small but **extremely** vital plastic piece snapped off. Can I order a new key from Apple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try a local Apple Store or Mac repair shop. There's a good chance they have a few dead keyboards laying around that they'd be willing to give you a replacement key from.

Comment: +1. I've heard of people getting new keys popped into their keyboards free of charge. Depends if they have any lying around the mood of the Genius. Doesn't hurt to ask. I've seen replacement keys for notebooks, but never the old standalone keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

You can get replacement parts from apple vie telephone, genius bar or authorized repair centers. The small scissors from the aluminum keyboards are the same as the unibody portable keys, and if they don't have that exact piece you need (large keys generally are unique pieces) they can order a replacement keyboard.